# Soft question: References for Dedekind's work on quaternions and hypercomplex numbers?

Tags: reference-request, quaternions, philosophy, hypercomplex-numbers

I've been told that quaternions and hypercomplex numbers in general were very important to Dedekind's early as well as late work. Besides Ferreiros' Labyrinth of Thought, ch. 7 and the references therein, I was unable to find any literature that would substantiate this claim re. the importance of quaternions (not quaternion groups!) and hypercomplex numbers for Dedekind. If anyone has any pointers, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: I hope someone can answer your question, but just in case note that there is a stackexchange site dedicated to history of maths and science: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @CaptainLama thanks for the heads-up, I didn't know! will bear it in mind for next time ;)